# Postgres JSON equivalent to HSTORE subtract operator

Tags: json, postgresql, hstore, postgresql-json, jsonb

Postgres' `hstore` extension has a neat subtraction operator:

```
hstore - text[]

hstore - hstore
```

In the first case, it removes the key/value pairs where the keys are found in the array of strings: in the second case it removes all matching key/value pairs from the first hstore that appear in the second hstore.

It seems this operator does not exist for the new `jsonb` data type. Is there a simple way to perform these tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the [`json_each()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) function, and the ability in PostgreSQL to manually build up a json value.

Here is a function which can handle `json - text[]`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "json_object_delete_keys"(
  "json" json,
  VARIADIC "keys_to_delete" TEXT[]
)
  RETURNS json
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
AS $function$
SELECT COALESCE(
  (SELECT ('{' || string_agg(to_json("key") || ':' || "value", ',') || '}')
     FROM json_each("json")
    WHERE "key" <> ALL ("keys_to_delete")),
  '{}'
)::json
$function$;
```

To handle the `json - json` case, you simple need to change the `WHERE` clause:

```
    WHERE "json"->>"key" <> ("remove"->>"key")),
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd come up with a plpython version, but this looks to be around 4 orders of magnitude faster!

Comment: Although, the `json - json` requires that the key/value pair be the same in the target and removal object.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel you're right, the `json - json` case is special. My first thought would be use an sql `EXCEPT` over the two `json_each()` sets, but `"json"->>"key" <> ("remove"->>"key")` is better.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is great, but would be improved for the `json - json` case by checking for null as well:

```
WHERE NOT null_as_value_cmp((this_j->>"key"), (that_j->>"key"))
```

Without the `NULL` check you get `{}` instead of `{"a":1}`:

```
# select json_subtract('{"a":1, "b":2}'::json, '{"b":2}'::json);
 json_subtract
---------------
 {}
(1 row)
```

`null_as_value_cmp` is something like this and gets around `JsNull` being represented as the database `NULL`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION null_as_value_cmp(
    a text,
    b text
)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
AS $function$
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN a IS NULL AND b IS NULL THEN
            TRUE
        WHEN (a IS NULL AND b IS NOT NULL) THEN
            FALSE
        WHEN (a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NULL) THEN
            FALSE
        WHEN a = b THEN
            TRUE
        ELSE
            FALSE
    END;
$function$;
```

[I don't have enough reputation to comment; not sure on the SO protocol here.]

Comment: I'm afraid `json - json` will never be ideal, because there is no equality operator for `json` (the best that we can do is to check their representation's equality) -- if OP (or anyone, who's interested in this) can use use 9.4+, I would highly recommend the `jsonb` type, which has equality operator; something like `(this_j->"key")::jsonb <> (that_j->"key")::jsonb` would do the job

Comment: @pozs Great point, I ran into a bunch of trouble with representation (in this case text) equality versus proper json comparison. I've updated above.

[We would love to use 9.4 jsonb, but have to wait for RDS support.]